# Maintaining Generation Data when Backing Up Versioned Google Cloud Storage Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage, versioning, backup-strategies

My use cases:

1. I would like to store multiple versions of text files in Cloud Storage and save the `createdAt` timestamp at which each version was created.
2. I'd like to be able to retrieve a list of all versions and `createdAt` times without opening and reading the files.
3. I'd also like to create nightly backups of the bucket with all the versions intact, and for each file to keep a record of its *original* `createdAt` time.

My solutions:

1. I have a Cloud Storage bucket with versioning enabled. Every time a I save a file `test`, I get a new file `test#generation_number`.
2. I can list all versions and fetch an older version with `test#generation_number`
3. I can back up all versions of `test` in the bucket, using `gsutil cp -A gs://my-original-bucket/test gs://my-backup-bucket`.

The issue with point #3. The `#generation_number` of each version that is backed up changes to the time at which the version of each backup file was created, *not* the time of the original file creation. I understand this is working as intended, and the order of the versions is still intact.

But where to stash these original `createdAt` values? I tried to store them in metadata, and I found metadata seems not to be versioned, but rather global for the file object as a whole.

What is the best way to achieve my use case? Is there any way to do so directly with Google Cloud Storage? Or should I maintain a separate database with this information, instead?

Comment: Howdy and welcome to Stackoverflow.  Got to thinking about your puzzle and a question comes to mind.  Given that Google gives us 11 9's of durability of the data and every time you make a new save, the old version is also stored ... what is the higher level thinking of you creating a "backup" yourself?  What does a manually created backup give you that you don't get without even taking a backup in the first place?

Comment: @Kolban Hmm, indeed my bucket is multi-regional, so it's already geo-redundant. I suppose my thinking is just the paranoid programmer in me saying "you should really back this up somewhere else, just in case." You make a good point: maybe I'm paying the platform to offload that "just in case", and the solution for my "problem" is not obvious because the problem doesn't really exist! I'll think on it a bit more, but that would indeed be a happy conclusion.